# Testing Pointer Functions in C

Tags: c, pointers, testing, arguments

I have to make functions similar (but more complex) than these. We aren't running them, just ensuring these pointers are receiving the values given. Are there any quick and easy ways to test and make sure we are doing these types of problems correct? My issue is, what kind of parameter could I pass into this function to test it?

```
int function(int *n)
{
    *n = 3;
}
```

Comment: Since the parameter type is pointer to integer, I suggest you pass it a pointer to an integer.  E.g. `int x = 5; function(&x); ...`

Comment: What you want to test. Be sure that compiler will not make any mistakes :)

Comment: You could add an `assert(n != 0);` or `assert(n != NULL);` at the top of the function to ensure that null pointers aren't passed to the function.  Otherwise, validating that you've been passed a correct `int` pointer is hard work (very hard work — there isn't a standard way to do it).  You may be able to reject pointers that are not pointing to a multiple of the type size (so a multiple of 4 for `int *` on a typical machine — but even that isn't reliable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try passing an address in to the function:

```
int storeThree(int *p) {
    *p = 3;
}

// Test function
void test() {
    int x = 5; //any integer other than what storeThree is going to fill
    storeThree(&x);
    assert(x == 3);
}
```

Comment: This isn't a very good test, since even if `x` ends up being 3, there's no way to know it didn't contain 3 to begin with (since its value is unspecified prior to the call).  To test it properly, you should assign a value to x (other than 3) before making the call to `storeThree`.